# Return List<objects> from a projection interface using Hql query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, hql

I have a `LineItem` entity an

```java
@Entity
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
public class LineItem extends AbstractEntity<LineItem>
{
    private int rank;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private OrderEntity orderEntity;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Service service;

    private long quantity;
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<HyperFile> files = new ArrayList<HyperFile>();
```

HyperFile

```
@Embeddable
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
public class HyperFile
{
    private String material;
    private String type;
.....
```

And projection DTP of `LineItem`

```java
ºublic interface RFQDto
{
    Service getService();

    List<HyperFile> getFiles();

    LineItemStatus getStatus();

    UUID getId();

    LocalDateTime getUpdated();

    long getQuantity();

    OrderEntity getOrderEntity();

    interface OrderEntity
    {
        OrderStatus getStatus();
    }

    interface List<HyperFile>
    {
        UUID getId();

    }
```

I want to retrieve RFQDto projection of `LineItem` from `LineitemRepository` with its fields but I can not get files field

```java
public interface LineItemRepository
        extends PagingAndSortingRepository<LineItem, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<LineItem>
{
    Optional<LineItem> findOneByIdAndOrderEntity_Organization_Id(UUID id, UUID orgId);

    @Query("SELECT l.id AS id, l.service AS service," + "l.status AS status,l.updated AS updated," + "l.files As files"
            + "l.quantity AS quantity," + "l.orderEntity As orderEntity FROM LineItem l "
            + "WHERE l not in (select q.lineItem from Quotation q where q.partner=?2)   "
            + "and l.service in (?1) and l.status=?3 and l.orderEntity.status=?4")
    Page<RFQDto> findByServiceIn(List<Service> services, Organization org, LineItemStatus status,
            OrderStatus orderStatus, Pageable page);
...
```

returns exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
```

and when removing "l.files As files" from the query it runs but returns null in files field

How to return files as a List of objects using the query.

Comment: What's the root cause for the error you're getting? I suspect Spring Data does not like mixing interface-based and class-based projections. Try declaring an interface for the `Hyperfile` getters and using it as the element type for the `RFQDto.files` list instead

Comment: declare it inside projection interface if so this does not work

Comment: HyperFile is in element collection